# Formula to place amount on a monthly timeline

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a monthly timeline that spans several years in columns C:AC.

I want to specify in three cells

```
Amount: £50
Start Date: Oct-15
Months: 6
```

And repeat this amount for 6 months starting October in each year, on the timeline.

Comment: I have tried: =IF(AND(DATEVALUE(J$9)>=EOMONTH($E106,0),DATEVALUE(J$9)<=EOMONTH($F106,0)),$D106,0)

Comment: this works but it considers two date values: start and end

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: What data are in J$9, $E106, etc.?

Comment: Instead of an end date - I would like to specify number of months. J$9 contains the monthly timeline i.e. 31-Dec-15  - $E106 is the start date input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```
=IF(AND(DATEVALUE(J$9)>=EOMONTH($E106,0),DATEVALUE(J$9)<=EDATE(EOMONTH($E106,0),6)),$D106,0)
```

`EDATE(SomeDate,6)` gives a date 6 months after SomeDate.

If you need to specify a date difference that is not an integer number of months from StartDate, DATE(year, month, day) will give you more flexibility:

```
DATE(YEAR(StartDate)+DeltaYears,MONTH(StartDate)+DeltaMonths,DAY(StartDate)+DeltaDays))
```

Hope that helps